# do i need a web page to publish app in appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to submit an app to the appstore. Read the "Prepare for app submission" topic in dev center. It says that i need Application URL and Support URL. So, i need to create a web page of my app in order to publish it in appstore? Is that necessary? I'm registered as an individual developer.

Comment: If you don't have a web page, where are users supposed to go when they need support (e.g. if they run into bugs in your app)?

Comment: i think support e-mail provided in the app will be enough. anyway, thanks for the feedback, i'll create the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required, but apparently all Apple really needs is a splash page. When Tiny Wings was released, for example, all the developer had up was a single page website with his contact info.